# How to solve the null object reference?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set width for image progragmaticall?

This is my code,

```
    txtone = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    txttwo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    height = metrics.heightPixels;
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    if (height == 800 && width == 1217) {
    int a = txtone.getMeasuredWidth();
    txtone.getLayoutParams().width = 280;
    txttwo.getLayoutParams().width = 280;
    txtthree.getLayoutParams().width = 280;
    txtone.requestLayout();
    txttwo.requestLayout();
    txtthree.requestLayout();
```

Comment: It means your txtone is not yet inflated and you are doing layout parameter operations on it

Comment: txttwo is not initialize

Comment: @Aman Grovercan you tell me how to do that

Comment: @Aman Groverca.  'FrameLayout. LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) txtone.getLayoutParams();'    i tried this but getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try to use one of `txttwo` `txtthree` before actually initializing them. One of them is `null`, when you call

```
txttwo.getLayoutParams().width = 280;
txtthree.getLayoutParams().width = 280;
```

As for your code, you didn't initialize `txtthree`

Comment: i did it.  but getting same error

Comment: @Aruna, did what? I didn't suggest a solution, I explained why you get error.

Comment: please check my edited code

Comment: Thank you so much. yes i didn't initialized txtone

Comment: @Aruna, you didn't initialize txtthree